# How to resolve the highlight active menu in css

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am a beginner in designing and I want to highlight the active menu
I did some R&D but I have find a solution regarding for list
**In my case list  is  not using for Menu**

here is my menu code:

```html
<aside id="nextendaccordionmenuwidget-2" class="widget NextendAccordionMenuWidget">
  <nav>
    <div id="nextend-accordion-menu-nextendaccordionmenuwidget-2" class="">
      <div class="nextend-accordion-menu-inner ">
        <div class="title">
          <h3>Menu</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="nextend-accordion-menu-inner-container">
          <dl class="level1 ">
            <dt class="level1 nextend-nav-82 notparent   first" data-menuid="82">
              <span class="outer">
                <span class="inner">
                  <a href="https://manresa-sj.com/">
                    <span>Home</span>
                  </a>  
                </span>
              </span>
            </dt>
            <dd class="level1 nextend-nav-82 notparent first"></dd>
            <dt class="level1 nextend-nav-38 parent" data-menuid="38" title="Click to open!">
              <span class="outer">
                <span class="inner">
                  <a href="https://manresa-sj.com/about-us/">
                    <span>About Us</span>
                  </a>
                </span>
              </span>
            </dt>
            <dd class="level1 nextend-nav-38 parent"></dd>
          </dl>
          <dl class="level2 ">
            <dt class="level2 nextend-nav-305 notparent   first" data-menuid="305">
              <span class="outer">
                <span class="inner">
                  <a href="https://manresa-sj.com/our-spirituality/">
                    <span>Our Spirituality</span>
                  </a>
                </span>
              </span>
            </dt>
          </dl>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</aside>
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. What is the expected behavior and what is the behavior you're getting. Can you share the relevant CSS, and can you reduce the problem so there's not so much HTML to look through?

Comment: You should add your css, at least

Comment: As WinK said, please add your CSS so we can better help. Are you asking to highlight the menu item when you hover over it with your cursor? Or do you want to highlight the current page in the nav list? (For example, if you click "Home" and go to the home page, now "home" is highlighted?)

Comment: @katniss.everbean yes I am asking about if I click "Home" and go to the home page, now "home" is highlighted

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using Nextend Accordion Menu to generate the menu. Here is what the author sais on the plugin site https://wordpress.org/plugins/nextend-accordion-menu/

> <del>Complete control from the backend over colors, backgrounds, images,
>   fonts etc. level by level and state by state (**active**, hover etc.)</del>

So I belive you have to tell the plugin to add the `.active`(or similar) class to the active menu. Then you can customize this class using some CSS rule like this:

```
.active { border:2px red solid; }
```

**EDIT**

It seems that the plugins author is referring to the actual **link state** and not to the **current page**. On the other hand the plugin handles well current page detection. So you will just have to customize the `.active` class.

Here is a small extraction from the source code of this page that contains a demo of the menu plugin: http://nextendweb.com/demo/accordionmenu/vehicles-bold/emma-maersk.html

```
<dd class="level3 nextend-nav-1982 notparent opened active"></dd>
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: I think in this case "active" refers to the link state active. A link is only active when it's actually being clicked.

Comment: Yes, yo're right. I believe the plugin author refers to the state of the link here.

Answer (score 0):

### :active won't work here

First, I'll point out that anything you find about the link state `a:active` won't help here. `:active` is similar to `:hover` in that it only applies when there is a particular mouse event. `:active` only applies when the mouse is actually being clicked.

`:active` does not select the link that corrisponds to the current page, so it won't work for the question asked here.

### what will work

To solve this problem, you'll need to write CSS rules for your links that apply only if they're inside a certain page. For example, the home link's rules would only apply if you're on the home page.

Wordpress applies different [body classes](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/body_class/) depending on the page you're on. For example, the home page's body element automatically gets the class "home".  There are [many others](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/wordpress-body-class-101-tips-and-tricks-for-theme-designers/), and you should be ably to use developer tools like Chrome Dev Tools, or Firebug to inspect your page and see which classes are getting applied to the body of each page you want to link to.

You'll also want to add a class or an ID to each link section you want to style so they're easier to select in your CSS.

You haven't included your CSS so I can't tell which sections you should add the IDs to. I've taken a guess in the code below just for demonstration.

```css
body.home #home-link {
  /* your styles here */
  }
```

```html
<aside id="nextendaccordionmenuwidget-2" class="widget NextendAccordionMenuWidget">
  <nav>
    <div id="nextend-accordion-menu-nextendaccordionmenuwidget-2" class="">
      <div class="nextend-accordion-menu-inner ">
        <div class="title">
          <h3>Menu</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="nextend-accordion-menu-inner-container">
          <!-- ----ADD AN ID----- -->
          <dl class="level1" id="home-link">
            <dt class="level1 nextend-nav-82 notparent   first" data-menuid="82">
              <span class="outer">
                <span class="inner">
                  <a href="https://manresa-sj.com/">
                    <span>Home</span>
                  </a>  
                </span>
              </span>
            </dt>
            <dd class="level1 nextend-nav-82 notparent first"></dd>
            <dt class="level1 nextend-nav-38 parent" data-menuid="38" title="Click to open!">
              <span class="outer">
                <span class="inner">
                  <a href="https://manresa-sj.com/about-us/">
                    <span>About Us</span>
                  </a>
                </span>
              </span>
            </dt>
            <dd class="level1 nextend-nav-38 parent"></dd>
          </dl>
          <dl class="level2 ">
            <dt class="level2 nextend-nav-305 notparent   first" data-menuid="305">
              <span class="outer">
                <span class="inner">
                  <a href="https://manresa-sj.com/our-spirituality/">
                    <span>Our Spirituality</span>
                  </a>
                </span>
              </span>
            </dt>
          </dl>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</aside>
```